# HTML tabs is not working sample

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i want to display the data in tabs , but here my data is displaying in single tab.
some one please help me out .

```html
</head>

<body>
    <div id='childarpt' class='childarpt'>
        </br>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="active "><a href="#Total "><span>Total</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#USA "><span>USA</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#ASIA "><span>ASIA</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#JAPAN "><span>JAPAN</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#LATAM "><span>LATAM</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#EMEA "><span>EMEA</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <table id='myTable' border='0'>
                <div id="Total " class="tab active ">
                    Total
                </div>
                <div id="USA " class="tab ">
                    USA
                </div>
                <div id="ASIA " class="tab ">
                    ASIA
                </div>
                <div id="JAPAN " class="tab ">
                    JAPAN
                </div>
                <div id="LATAM " class="tab ">
                    LATAM
                </div>
                <div id="EMEA " class="tab ">
                    EMEA
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $("#tabs ").tabs();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

here all the div data is displaying in the first tab , remaining div data is not hiding .

Comment: is it `jquery-ui` tabs??

Comment: There is a typo `<ul ">` here. Also, show what references does the `<head>` contain.

Comment: Was about to edit my answer to mention this!! Anyways you informed @ShaunakD :)

Comment: Similarly `table` is not required!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='childarpt' class='childarpt' ></br>
  <div id="tabs"><ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#Total"><span>Total</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#USA"><span>USA</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#ASIA"><span>ASIA</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#JAPAN"><span>JAPAN</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#LATAM"><span>LATAM</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#EMEA"><span>EMEA</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <table id='myTable' border='0'>

  <div id="Total" class="tab active">
  Total
  </div>
   <div id="USA" class="tab">
   USA
  </div>
  <div id="ASIA" class="tab">
    ASIA
  </div>
   <div id="JAPAN" class="tab">
   JAPAN
  </div>
   <div id="LATAM" class="tab">
   LATAM
  </div>
   <div id="EMEA" class="tab">
   EMEA
  </div>
 
  </table>
  </div>
```

Include `jquery-lastest.js` and `jquery-ui.js` file. **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mq4dxz8h/)**

Comment: if i replace sample DIV elements with actual ones like given below are not working

Comment: then you need to post the actual code which is causing problem! Create a fiddle if possible