# HTML Jquery tab is not working

Tags: jquery, html

This is a part of my previous question [HTML tabs is not working sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635102/html-tabs-is-not-working-sample)

Here is the my code :

```js
$("#tabs ").tabs();
```

```css
#nav,
    #nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    #nav li {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    #nav liaa {
        padding-left: 17px;
        background: url(iarrow.gif) left top no-repeat;
        padding-bottom: .45em;
    }
    
    #nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #960000;
    }
    
    #nav a:hover {
        color: #1b53b9;
    }
    
    #nav .expandable {
        padding-left: 0px;
        background-image: none;
    }
    
    .reportcont {
        position: relative;
        left: 2px;
        top: 0;
        width: 99%;
        overflow: scroll;
        border: 0px solid #ccc;
    }

a {
        font-family: Arial, serif;
        font-weight: regular;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-color: #000080;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    a:link {
        font-color: #000080;
    }
    
    a:visited {
        color: #B00081;
    }

.busHead {
        background-color: #D5E5ED;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-color: #0099CC;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .totHead {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-color: #000080;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .colHeadTot {
        border: 2px;
        font-family: Arial, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #000080;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #D5E5ED;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .colHead {
        border: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        font-family: Arial, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #0099CC;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #D5E5ED;
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .tabValBus {
        border-left: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-right: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-top: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-family: Arial, serif;
        font-weight: regular;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #000080;
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
    
    .tabVal {
        border-left: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-right: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-top: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #eeeeff;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-family: Arial, serif;
        font-weight: regular;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #000080;
        text-align: right;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .delta {
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: windings;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    
    .blue_row {
        background-color: #ccf2fc;
        color: #002d72;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .table_header {
        color: #00bdf2;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .table_headerH {
        color: #002d72;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .pageTitle1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*width: 774px;*/
        
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .pageTitle1 {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        color: #000066;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    
    .pageTitle1 h2 {
        color: #000066;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding-left: 2px;
    }
    
    .pageContainer1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        /* example: width: 955px; */
        
        margin-top: 0px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    #filterdiv {
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .reportContainer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
    
    .img-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
    
    .img-container>img {
        margin-top: -50%;
        margin-left: -50%;
        width: 10px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    
    .resizedTextbox {
        width: 100px;
        padding: 1px
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="us">

 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>tabs Sample</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/common_fixed.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/top_nav.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/styles09.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/colorbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/jquery.cluetip.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/form_controls.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div id='childarpt' class='childarpt'>
        </br>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="active "><a href="#Total "><span>Total</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#NAM "><span>NAM</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#ASIA "><span>ASIA</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#JAPAN "><span>JAPAN</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#LATAM "><span>LATAM</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#EMEA "><span>EMEA</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <table id='myTable' border='0'>
                <div id="Total " class="tab active ">
                    <tr>
                        <th class='colHead'>title</th>
                        <th class='colHead'></th>
                        <th class='colHead'>04-30-2015
                            <br> count</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Vol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Invol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Delta</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>***05-21-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>2015/05/21
                            <br>Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Pending
                            <br> Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Future
                            <br>Terms
                            <br>(Non-RIF)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Planned
                            <br> RIFs</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other CHC
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Net CHC
                            <br>Impact (thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>CHC
                            <br>Impact
                            <br>(thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>(2015/05/21) CHC
                            <br> Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                <div id="NAM " class="tab ">
                    <tr>
                        <th class='colHead'>Officer Title Detail</th>
                        <th class='colHead'></th>
                        <th class='colHead'>04-30-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Vol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Invol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Delta</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>***05-21-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>2015/05/21
                            <br>Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Pending
                            <br> Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Future
                            <br>Terms
                            <br>(Non-RIF)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Planned
                            <br> RIFs</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other CHC
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Net CHC
                            <br>Impact (thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>CHC
                            <br>Impact
                            <br>(thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>(2015/05/21) CHC
                            <br> Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                <div id="ASIA " class="tab ">
                    <div></div>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='colHead'>Officer Title Detail</th>
                        <th class='colHead'></th>
                        <th class='colHead'>04-30-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Vol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Invol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Delta</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>***05-21-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>2015/05/21
                            <br>Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Pending
                            <br> Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Future
                            <br>Terms
                            <br>(Non-RIF)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Planned
                            <br> RIFs</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other CHC
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Net CHC
                            <br>Impact (thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>CHC
                            <br>Impact
                            <br>(thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>(2015/05/21) CHC
                            <br> Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                <div id="JAPAN " class="tab ">
                    <div></div>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='colHead'>Officer Title Detail</th>
                        <th class='colHead'></th>
                        <th class='colHead'>04-30-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Vol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Invol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Delta</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>***05-21-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>2015/05/21
                            <br>Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Pending
                            <br> Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Future
                            <br>Terms
                            <br>(Non-RIF)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Planned
                            <br> RIFs</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other CHC
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Net CHC
                            <br>Impact (thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>CHC
                            <br>Impact
                            <br>(thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>(2015/05/21) CHC
                            <br> Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                <div id="LATAM " class="tab ">
                    <div></div>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='colHead'>Officer Title Detail</th>
                        <th class='colHead'></th>
                        <th class='colHead'>04-30-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Vol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Invol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Delta</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>***05-21-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>2015/05/21
                            <br>Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Pending
                            <br> Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Future
                            <br>Terms
                            <br>(Non-RIF)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Planned
                            <br> RIFs</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other CHC
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Net CHC
                            <br>Impact (thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>CHC
                            <br>Impact
                            <br>(thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>(2015/05/21) CHC
                            <br> Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                <div id="EMEA " class="tab ">
                    <div></div>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='colHead'>Officer Title Detail</th>
                        <th class='colHead'></th>
                        <th class='colHead'>04-30-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Vol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Invol
                            <br>Terms</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Delta</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>***05-21-2015
                            <br> Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>2015/05/21
                            <br>Actual HC</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Pending
                            <br> Hires</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Future
                            <br>Terms
                            <br>(Non-RIF)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Planned
                            <br> RIFs</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>**Other CHC
                            <br> Activity</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Net CHC
                            <br>Impact (thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>CHC
                            <br>Impact
                            <br>(thru
                            <br>2015/05)</th>
                        <th class='colHead'>Prior Week
                            <br>(2015/05/21) CHC
                            <br> Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table style="width:600px ">
            <tr>
                <th nowrap class='colHead'>Notes: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>*Promotions based on mobility codes for the timeframe selected (e.g. beginning to actual headcount).</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>**Other Activity includes Transfer In/Out and To/From Leave</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>***Ending headcount costs is the summation of annualized salary for active headcount at the time selected.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>All costs are in USD 1,000s</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table style="width:300px ">
            <tr>
                <th nowrap class='colHead'>Parameter Selections: </th>
                <th class='colHead'></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Layout 1:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>Officer Title Detail</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Layout 2:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>Job Group</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Mgd Segment:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>TOP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Mgd Geography:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>ALL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Physical Region:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>ALL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Physical Country:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>ALL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Officer Title:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>ALL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Standard Grade:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>ALL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Job Function/Family/Group:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>ALL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Layout View:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>Rows</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Include Committed Headcount:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Include Costs:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Historical Start Date:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>PME</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Historical End Date:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>CURRENT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap class='tabValBus'>Future End Date:</td>
                <td class='tabValBus'>CURRENT</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Please check the above code and advice . For sample data it is working fine , but is add more data to the div tags it is not working !

Comment: If this is part of the code for your previous question, please add it to that question and delete this one. You can edit a question as many times as you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `table` sturcture. So you have two options:

> - Either create separate `table` in each `div` and remove main `table` as in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mq4dxz8h/2/)** or
> - Remove the `div` and keep target ids for each `tr`s as in this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mq4dxz8h/1/)**

**You can choose either of one**

and yes not to forget @Tushar's suggestion to remove duplicate `jquery.js` and `jquery-ui.js`

Answer (score 0):

YOu 've included `jQuery` and `jQuery-ui` twice on the page. Remove one instance and it will work.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/common_fixed.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/top_nav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/styles09.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/colorbox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/jquery.cluetip.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssFilterPage/form_controls.css">
<!-- Removed Duplicate Scripts From Here -->
```

Comment: is adding <TR> in div causing this issue ??